# Parallelism (Threads and Processes)

Tags: parallel-processing

I have a question. I know the differece between a thread and a process in theory. But I still don't understand when we should use the first and when the latter. For example, we have a difficult task which needs to be parelleled. But in which way? Which is faster and MORE EFFECTIVE and in what cases? Should we split our task into a few processes or into a few threads? Could you give a few examples? I know that my question may seem silly, but I'm new to the topic of parallel computing. I hope that you understand my question. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In general, there is only one main difference between processes and threads: All threads of a given process share the same virtual address space.  Whereas each process has its own virtual address space.

When dealing with problems that require concurrent access to the same set of data, it is easier to use threads, because they can all directly access the same memory.

Comment: In modern OSes, processes share data (initially) too: copy-on-write. Therefore, any performance difference depends on the particular algorithm; a *parallel* but *non-concurrent* program might have similar performance characteristics in both OS-level threads and processes.

Comment: Take this answer with a grain of salt.  I don't think there's a widely accepted, authoritative distinction.   Widely used OSes such as Windows and Linux define processes and threads in the way Jonathan says, so generally this is what people mean.  But in general, if you don't know the context of the discussion, you need to ask how much of the virtual machine state is shared by any process or thread or fork or fiber or task or activity or ...  whatever the apparantly parallel construct being discussed is.  (+1 because I think this answer conveys the widely used understanding well).

Comment: @IraBaxter You are correct - I really only tried to answer this in a very high-level general case, according to the most common cases (Windows, Linux).

Comment: This answer needs to be read precisely - copy-on-write means sharing physical memory when possible, but it does not mean sharing a virtual address space, as that will necessarily diverge the instant the first unique page is mapped in the process of creating the child.

Answer (score 1):

Threads share memory.  Processes do not.

This means that processes are somewhat more expensive to start up.  It also means that threads can conveniently communicate through shared memory, and processes cannot.

However, from a coding perspective, it also means that threads are significantly more difficult to program correctly.  It's very easy for threads to stomp on each others' memory in unintended ways.  Processes are somewhat safer.

Welcome to the world of concurrency!

Comment: Threads are not *inherently* difficult to program. In a type-safe functional language like Haskell, for instance, much of the difficulties are abstracted away. It's a matter of *which* threading implementation you're using.

Comment: In the general case, threaded code must deal with deadlocks and race conditions.  Any language that prevents the programmer from dealing with those issues also gives up much of the power that threaded programming can provide.

Comment: Yes, in general - though a capable operating system may allow sharing read only or copy-on-write memory between processes which either have a common ancestry (as an extreme example the shared mapping of most system libraries on Android), or explicitly requestable shared memory mechanisms intended for interprocess communication.

Answer (score 0):

There is no theoretical difference between threads and processes that is practical to generalize from. There are many, many different ways to implement threads, including ways that nearly mirror those of processes (e.g. Linux threads). Then there's lightweight threading, which involves the process managing the threading by itself; but there's more variation there, because you can then have either co-operative or semi-preemptive threading model.

For example, we describe Haskell's threading model and Python's.

Haskell offers lightweight threads that introduce little runtime overhead; there are well-defined points at which threads may yield control, but this is largely hidden from the user, giving the appearance of pre-emptive multitasking. Shared state is held in specially typed variables that are treated specially by the language. Because of this, multi-threaded, even *concurrent* programs can be written in a largely single-threaded way, then forked from the main process. So there, threads are and *abstraction mechanism*, and may even be beneficial in a single-(OS)-threaded process to model the program; however, it scales well to N-threads, where N may be chosen dynamically. (And N Haskell threads are mapped dynamically to OS threads.)

Python allows threading, but with a huge bottleneck: the Global Interpreter lock. Therefore, to gain serious performance benefits, one must use processes in practice. There is no feasible, performant threading model to speak of.